# "Delete profile" option is no longer present in one's user settings page

Tags: bug, status-completed, deleted-accounts, preferences

Not Meta. https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/deleting-account refers to

> [image]

I am on the MAIN site. **BUT I do not see "Delete profile"!**

> [image]

In case this was removed on purpose, can we:

1. Know the reason why?
2. Have the option to delete our accounts again?

Comment: Definitely a bug. In the meantime, you can navigate to `/users/delete/current` on the site; notice that going there doesn't highlight any option in the left pane.

Comment: Reproduced as high rep account too, used to have option to delete my account, and it went poof. Might be on purpose, not a bug, SE making lots of changes without announcing. (Usually just design, but we can't know.)

Answer (score 9):

Sorry about that one folks! Some reorganization we pushed for that sidebar hid that menu from our public sites. We've reverted that change and it should now be back up.

Just for some quick info, the "Delete profile" button is now next to "Edit profile" in the "Personal information" section. The Help Center article has been updated.

Thank you for reporting!

Comment: The screenshot in the Help Center page "How do I delete my account?" (located at `/help/deleting-account`) has now been updated network-wide.

Comment: I was about to come with guns blazing saying something like "How come you didn't check the sidebar on the public sites after deploying a change to the sidebar?!", however ironically enough, customer just complained about a critical new bug in something I deployed a change to yesterday, without checking properly. So, should point those guns at myself as well. Anyhow, thanks!