# I cannot find the delete my profile button

Tags: support, deleted-accounts

I am trying to delete my profile on a SE site, but I cannot see delete profile under the Personal information tab. Can someone help?

Should be an easy process. I am looking for half an hour to find a way to delete an account. Where has the button gone? Got me thinking maybe SE wants to keep us for good!?

Comment: This is unfortunately a bug that hides the section where this is visible: ["Delete profile" option is no longer present in one's user settings page](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/381167/delete-profile-option-is-no-longer-present-in-ones-user-settings-page)

Comment: In the meantime, as mentioned in the comments of that post, you can go to `$site/users/delete/current` on whichever SE site you're trying to do this on to get where you want to go.

Comment: @zcoop98 Been there, done that! Thanks!

Comment: That [isn't the only thing that is broken](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/380834/).

Comment: About 45 minutes after you asked this, the bug was fixed.